# Optimizar Cursor SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el siguiente query el cual uso un cursor para recorrer un registro en un SP, de momento todo lo hace bien sin embargo
al ser cursor pues tarda

Mi consulta es, como puedo hacer este recorrido sin utilizar Cursor para que sea mas optima la consulta

este es el query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TempLoanAppli') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempLoanAppli

--===================================================
--Tabla Temporal para almacenar datos de los Cursores
--===================================================
CREATE TABLE #TempLoanAppli 
(
NoCredito NVARCHAR(30) ,
NombreCliente NVARCHAR(255),
FechaPago DATE,
FechaQuePago DATE,
CumplePagoPuntual VARCHAR(10),
AplicaMejoraCategoria NVARCHAR(30),
CategoriaMejorar VARCHAR(80),
FormaPago VARCHAR(80)
);


--=================================================
--    Creditos con Forma de Pago Mensual
--=================================================


DECLARE @NumCredito NVARCHAR(30); 

-------------------------------------------
---------------INICIO CURSOR---------------
-------------------------------------------

DECLARE Cursor_Mensual CURSOR FOR 

SELECT 
ci.[No. Crédito] AS NumCredito

FROM Creditos ci

OPEN Cursor_Mensual;

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Mensual
INTO 
   @NumCredito;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO #TempLoanAppli

EXEC DetallePlanPagoMejoraCategoria @NumCredito

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Mensual
INTO 
@NumCredito;

END;

CLOSE Cursor_Mensual;
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Mensual;


SELECT * FROM #TempLoanAppli

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TempLoanAppli') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempLoanAppli
```

Comment: No podemos contestar -y no lo podrás resolver- sin el código de `DetallePlanPagoMejoraCategoria`.

Comment: el código de ese SP es demasiado grande por eso no lo coloque, si ejecuto simplemente el SP tarda 1 segundo, pero al ejecutarlo dentro del cursor como lo estoy haciendo tarda entre 5 a 10 minutos por el recorrido crédito por crédito que realiza

Comment: Por eso, es mas probable que el problema esté ahí que en una consulta tan  simple `select columna from tabla`. ¿Cúantos créditos son? multiplicalo por 1 segundo.

Comment: Unicamente son 700 creditos, con el cursor me tarda entre 5 a 10 minutos

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacerlo con un WHILE, editare la pregunta

Comment: Ahí esta: 700 créditos x 1s = 700 s = 11.6 minutos. Tendrías que optimizar el SQL de ese procedimiento para que tarde mucho menos que medio segundo. Aunque tengas un ferrari, si el piloto pesa 200 Kg...

Comment: De igual forma, quiero saber si existe una forma para recorrer lo que estoy haciendo en el query sin usar cursores, se podra?

Comment: Es bastante probable, que no necesites un cursor. Pero si no pones el código que hace el procedimiento `DetallePlanPagoMejoraCategoria`, es imposible saberlo. El hecho de usar un cursor o usar while, en esos tiempos no cambiará absolutamente nada. Y si quieres mantener la llamada al procedimiento, entonces si tendrás que hacer un bucle. Ahora bien, a lo mejor el procedimiento puede tener como parámetro una Tipo de Sql y entonces no hace un bucle externo, y modificando el procedimiento mencionado es mucho más efectivo. Pero al final todo depende del código del procedimiento.

Comment: Puedes optimizar las opciones del cursor, pero el problema es que estás repitiendo 700 veces un proceso que dura un segundo. Para solucionar tu problema es necesario adaptar el código de `DetallePlanPagoMejoraCategoria`.